# Android Webview dont use imported font from CSS file

Tags: android, css, webview, fonts

Im using a webview in android to show a html webpage with css and imported fonts but the webview dont use the imported fonts. How can i make it work?

The font is imported inside the css file:

[image]

Font in webview:

[image]

Font in browser:

[image]

Android webview configuration:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Same point here! Have you solved this issue? how? thanks so much!